# Диск замонтированный как папка

Tags: c#, .net, windows

В Windows можно замонтировать диск, как папку. Например, когда все буквы под диски заняты.

Как можно понять, что папка, с которой работает программа- это отдельный диск?

Как узнать свободное место на этом замонтированном диске?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Как можно понять, что папка, с которой работает программа- это отдельный диск?

Если нужно просто понять, что это не простая папка, то можно посмотреть список атрибутов на предмет наличия атрибута `FileAttributes.ReparsePoint`. Делается стандартным способом:

```
var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo("FolderFullName");
if((dInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Это самая обычная папка.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Эта папка не такая простая, как кажется!");
```

Проблема в том, что атрибут Reparse Point есть у всех объектов файловой системы специального назначения, будь то монтированные диски, символьные ссылки и прочие забавные объекты, о существовании и наличии которых вы, возможно, даже не догадывались (я тоже знаю и видел в живую далеко не все). Подробности можно почитать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503(v=vs.85).aspx) (к сожалению, родная документация не переведена) и [тут](http://hex.pp.ua/reparse-points.php)(скромненько, но по-русски).

> Как узнать свободное место на этом замонтированном диске?

А вот это уже интересная задача. `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` может показать только диски (вернее разделы дисков), которым назначена "Буква диска", иными словами,  имеют изолированное дерево файловой системы. Если монтированному диску назначена и буква, и точка монтирования (да так тоже можно), то он, разумеется, будет в этом списке, но легче от этого не становится.

Единственный гарантированный вариант получить необходимую информацию - запросить ее через WMI. Варианты с ручного низкоуровневого копания в содержимом "подозрительного" объекта ФС оставим для C++, да и антивирусы на такое иногда неадекватно реагируют или наоборот адекватно, но от этого не легче.

За точки монтирования отвечает WMI-класс `Win32_MountPoint`. Объекты данного класса содержат две WMI-ссылки, на папку монтирования и логический диск. Получить их довольно легко.

```
var namespaceScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\ROOT\CIMV2");
var diskQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_MountPoint");
var mgmtObjSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(namespaceScope, diskQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection mountPoints = mgmtObjSearcher.Get();

foreach (var mp in mountPoints)
{
    //Получаем доступ к объекту Win32_Directory (папка к которой примонтирован диск)
    var dirObj = new ManagementObject(mp.Properties["Directory"].Value as string));
    //Получаем доступ к объекту Win32_Volume (раздел диска который примонтирован к папке)
    var volumeObj = new ManagementObject(mp.Properties["Volume"].Value as string));
}
```

Получение свойств самих объектов не представляет особой сложности, списки свойств можно найти тут: [Win32_MountPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394205(v=vs.85).aspx), [Win32_Volume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx), [Win32_Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394130(v=vs.85).aspx)

Одно важное замечание, перед обращениям к свойствам объекта, надо убедиться, что объект получен без ошибок, или обернуть в `try-catch`, потому что объект возвращается даже при отсутствии доступа к папке или разделу, например при изъятом из DVD-привода диске. Объект будет находиться в невалидном состоянии и при обращении к свойствам произойдет исключение.

Дальше уже дело техники: получаем точки монтирования, находим нужную, запрашиваем свойства раздела.